# Switching View Controllers within a Container View programmatically - Swift and OS X

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

Using Swift 2.0 for an OS X (10.9) application, I wish to programmatically switch a view controller (a Tab View Controller) within a Container View to another view controller (i.e. replace the Tab View Controller with another View Controller). This would occur when the 'Install' button is clicked on either of the tab views and some condition is met (thus the need for doing so programmatically). I do not want to use segues (unless a custom segue which replaces the window, rather than opens up a modal etc.).

I'm very much a beginner with Swift and mac development, and have had no luck finding a solution from a reliable and intelligible source (for a beginner) for something I know should be quite simple.

[image]